# group by and filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Article
in mydb

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | keywords               |
+----+------------------------+
| 83 | automotive, pet, heath |
| 82 | car, plane             |
| 81 | NULL                   |
| 80 | pet, car               |
| 78 | Null                   |
+----+------------------------+
```

I want t get result same as:

```
{
"automotive" => [82], 
"pet" => [82,80], 
"heath" => [83], 
"plane" => [82], 
"car" => "80" 
}
```

how do i get result same as data above??

Comment: is your keywords another table?

Comment: Can you change the schema? CSV-in-a-column is a bit of anti-pattern.

Comment: no, it is a string @oreoluwa

Answer (score 0):

Basically, set the keywords as the key of the hash, and keep insert article id into the corresponding array

```
summary = Hash.new()
Article.all.each do |a|
  if a.keywords
    # assuming your keywords is stored as a string
    a.keywords.split(", ").each do |keyword|
      if summary[keyword].empty?
        summary[keyword] = [a.id]
      else
        summary[keyword].push(a.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```